# How to call a function inside a bash script on Raspbian?

Tags: bash, raspbian

I have this script that I use on Centos for many years. I am calling the same script on Raspberry Pi now and I get this error:

```
/media/Backups/backup_all.sh: 2: /media/Backups/backup_all.sh: source: not found
/media/Backups/backup_all.sh: 7: /media/Backups/backup_all.sh: function: not found
```

This is the script which is in a file called backup_all.sh. I call it from the command line and cron using sh backup_all.sh.

```
#!/bin/sh
function backup
{
    sh "/media/Backups/backup.sh" $1 $2 filter-list.txt
}
backup myserverhostname.com 22
```

I also tried putting source backup.sh or "source /media/Backups/backup.sh" at the top and it didn't work.

The strange thing is it does actually call the backup.sh script because I get further errors from that.

If I call the source script direct from the command line (e.g. sh "/media/Backups/backup.sh" myserverhostname.com 22 filter-list.txt) it runs OK, so I dont think there are errors in there.

If I dont use the function and just call sh "/media/Backups/backup.sh" myserver 22 filter-list.txt in the backup_all.sh file, then that also works OK. So seems to be just when used in a function.

For info I am including the script inside another script because I iterate through many servers to run this function, so I call the backup function in this file many times, it was easier than calling it specifically for each server. But to make it work I am removing the function and calling each line separately, but would be good to find out why I cant use the same function as on Centos.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like `/media/Backups/backup.sh` is a Bash script rather than a standard (POSIX) shell script. Likewise, the syntax for `backup_all.sh` is only valid for Bash.

In Bash `source` is a builtin and `function` is a shell key-word but these are not specified in the [POSIX standard for sh](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sh.html), the shell command interpreter.  The shebang in your scripts is `#!/bin/sh` which instructs the kernel to use `/bin/sh` to interpret the script.

The reason both shell script worked with CentOS is that the Red Hat-based distributions create `/bin/sh` as a symbolic link to `/bin/bash`. Bash is (mostly) compatible with POSIX but extends its features in a number of ways. With recent Debian derivatives (such as Raspbian), `/bin/sh` is a symbolic link to `/bin/dash`, a POSIX shell that is stricter in its compatibility (but also more lightweight and faster than Bash).  That’s why the following errors are being thrown by the script interpreter:

```
/media/Backups/backup_all.sh: 2: /media/Backups/backup_all.sh: source: not found
/media/Backups/backup_all.sh: 7: /media/Backups/backup_all.sh: function: not found
```

This can be fixed by:

1. Explicitly specifying Bash as the interpreter in your `backup()` function as `bash /media/Backups/backup.sh "$1" "$2" filter-list.txt` (note that the variables are quoted).
2. Explicitly specifying Bash as the shebang for `backup_all.sh` (and `backup.sh`)

   ```
   #!/bin/bash
   ```

Alternatively, rewrite both scripts to be POSIX compatible and continue to use `/bin/sh` as the interpreter.  See the Ubuntu wiki article, [Dash as /bin/sh](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DashAsBinSh) for more information on this.

Comment: I added #!/bin/bash to backup_all.sh. But just occured to me I did not add it to backup.sh. Maybe thats the issue, i will try that, thanks a lot.